# For Kindle, are hard paragraph breaks that serious?

Tags: formatting, kindle

I'm starting with an existing .doc MS. Kindle warns to not use hard para breaks, i.e., don't hit return, but I can't get rid of any of them. Driving me nuts.

Comment: Hm, why should hard-breaks be a problem? That sounds weird. Maybe the real problem is the text indentation of the new paragraph. Soft-breaks are normally done with Shift+Return.

Comment: Have you misinterpreted the advice not to use ADDITIONAL hard returns? If you have hit return TWICE to create space between paragraphs (instead of using style formatting) then Kindle will see an empty paragraph and try to style it. That can look really ugly.

Comment: It only matters if you enter KDP select. And what do you mean you can't get rid of them? Is Word not removing them?

Comment: I don't understand how you can have a document without hitting Return. The whole thing would be one paragraph. I've converted .doc MSS to Kindle format, and there is nothing wrong with paragraphs.

Answer (score 3):

For ebooks, the general rule is, don't use two consecutive returns (as @Fortier mentioned in the comments). This is because the ebook readers sometimes do weird things with it.

However, this is just a suggestion, and almost every Ebook vendor will allow it. Kindle only moans if you enter KDP.

My advice is, write the book, and worry about formatting later. You can easily remove double returns using regexes, which works in Word and every other processor. Google can tell you how.

PS: I'm pretty sure I've answered this question earlier, but I can't find it now. Anyone else remember where it is?